# Resources for android phones with soft keys navigation

Tags: java, android

What is best practice for creating resolution specific resources for Android phones that use soft-keys for navigation?

Can I create a specific directory in the res folder, or should the resources be created at runtime?

I have specific resources for each resolution (currently, only 2 resolutions are supported), however, in case the phone has soft-keys, I will need different resources.

I know that this is bad design, but this decision is not up to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. I created a folders values-1184x720 and values-1280x720. Galaxy S 3 get resources from 1280x720 and Galaxy Nexus get resources from 1184x720. Since all targete devices with soft keys are with same resolution as Galaxy Nexus this solves my problem.

Soft keys are 48dp. In xhdpi this is 96px. So in resolution 1280x720 reals screen estate is 1184x720.